# Does launching app for an http link on Windows 10 require server-side changes?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10

I followed the guide [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking) to link my app to an https URI. It works perfectly fine during testing, for both Debug and Release versions: when I click a hyperlink for the website, the app is launched instead of Edge. The OnActivated event is triggered and the app goes to the desired page, all well and good.

Keep in mind, I'm not using the LaunchUriAsync technique that opens the link only if the app is in foreground.

But when I uploaded the app to the store and downloaded it on the same device I was testing on, the app is not launched. Instead, the webpage opens in Edge. Why is this happening? Is it really mandatory to do some server-side changes to make this work? I'm afraid I don't have access to that, as my app is a third party alternative.

Can someone informed on this topic tell me how I can go about this?

Also, the app does show up under the "Apps for websites" section in Settings -> System when installed through the Store.

Comment: Have you tried running that test on another device? Maybe the old installation from your debug testing left some traces on the devices that interfere with that functionality.

Comment: @Khawar Nadeem, were you able to get it to work without server side changes ? 
If yes, does it work only with test builds or does it also work for published apps as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document has a mistake before 8/26, The Json file name should be **"windows-app-web-link**", not "microsoft-app-uri-handlers". If you have referenced the previous document to lead to not work, please update.

If you still have issues after updated, please test the configuration of your app and website by running the App host registration verifier tool (Details please see the 'Test it out: Local validation tool' section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking)

Because according to the document,

> all side loaded apps with AppUriHandlers will have validated links for the host on install. You do not need to have a JSON file uploaded to test the feature. It seems may be something wrong with the JSON file so you can have a test.